# how to sort a SELECT in js

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a problem on this js. this script is used when i select "type". When the "type" I want is selected the program import the different option , create options and put it in the select named "intitule". My objectif is to sort options of the field "intitule" by alphabetical order, not by value. But I don't know how I can do that.

Could you help me.

Thanks

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#type').change(function() { 

            $("#intitule > option").remove(); 
            var idType = $('#type').val(); 
            console.log(idType);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://potato/?action=formation&page=formation_add&id=' + idType,
                
                success: function(intitule) 
                {
                    $('#intitule').append(new Option(
                            "--- Sélectionner ---",
                            ""
                        ));
                    $.each(intitule, function(id_Types, libelle_Types) 
                    {
                        $('#intitule').append(new Option(
                            libelle_Types,
                            id_Types
                        ));
                    });
                
                }
            });
            
        });
    });
```

```html
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Intitulé :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                      <select type="text" class="form-control" id="intitule" name="title">
                      </select>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Why not provide also a code sample of `intitule` response?

Comment: Why not do this on the server instead? `SELECT ... ORDER_BY libelle_type ASC`. If you can't, then you're looking for [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is not [consulting the API](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) nor inspecting the console log about what are exactly the `$.each` callback function arguments. What was presumed <s>`function(id_Types, libelle_Types)`</s> is actually `function(index, item)`.

Therefore, if the response Array has `item` Objects one should go like:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  const $intitule = $("#intitule");

  const createIntituleOptions = (data) => {
    $intitule.append(new Option("--- Sélectionner ---", ""));
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      $intitule.append(new Option(item.libelle_Types, item.id_Types));
    });
  };
  
  createIntituleOptions([
    {id_Types:23, libelle_Types:"TwentyThree"},
    {id_Types:45, libelle_Types:"FourthyFive"},
    {id_Types:12, libelle_Types:"Twelve"}
  ]);

});
```

```html
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Intitulé :</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <select type="text" class="form-control" id="intitule" name="title">
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use the above function like:

```
  success: createIntituleOptions,
```

Comment: Simply sort the data Array by the desired inner object property value